# Cannot assign value of type [NSObject] to type NSObject

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a problem saving an array `[String]` to core data.
In core data, I set the type for my field "countires" - Transformable.

I add data in the following way:

```
filters!.countries = selectedCountries as? [NSObject]
```

After that, build the project for the simulator or iPhone. 
There are no build errors.

[image]

But if I want to build an "archive" or "generic", the syntax error is highlighted. - "Cannot assign value of type [NSObject] to type NSObject."

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: For starters, shouldn't the question mark be after `as`?

Comment: The three(!) different spellings *countires*, *coutries* and *countries* are a bit confusing.

Comment: @vadian yeap, synthetic error. thx.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson is xcode suggested me to do %) In my case, it doesn't matter  after "as" or [NSObject]

Comment: Nobody keeps [String] in Core Data?
Of course I temporarily made simple string with "," - but I think is bad decision.

Comment: what does your core data definition of countries look like?

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of  "countries".. i think it is not an array of type NSObject

Comment: Countries field in the generated class is of type [NSObject]. This can be seen in the screenshot, where I hover the mouse on the field and look at its attributes.